# Yii2: Change Gridviews' DataProvider on button click

Tags: javascript, php, gridview, yii2, pjax

I have 3 seperate dataProviders for my Gridview, one with Saved data, one with Unsaved data and one with both.

Now this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

If you click on saved, the dataProvider changes to the one with saved data.

I'm trying it like this:

```
<?php 

if($i == 1){
    $dataProvider = $dataProviderSaved;
} elseif($i == 2) {
    $dataProvider = $dataProviderNotsaved;
} else {
    $dataProvider = $dataProviderBoth;
};

\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'gridview', 'timeout' => false,
 'enablePushState' => false, 'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]) ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //regular gridview..

\yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Javascript:

```
var i = $i;

$("#saved").click(function(){
i=1;
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;//IMPORTANT
$.pjax.reload({container:"#gridview"});
});

', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

So, I've just read that changing PHP variables inside JS is 'impossible'.

- How would I accomplish this?
- Is there a better way?
- Do I need 3
  DataProviders? (This means 3 find()'s inside of the controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood properly you don't need 3 dataProviders. You should use GridView's `FilterSelector` option to treat that external element as part of GridView's filter. 
For example

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterSelector' => "input[name='ModelSearch[_selection]'],",
    ...
```

Then, in your Filter Model you filter depending on that value

```
switch($this->_selection) {
    case 'Saved':
        $query->andFilterWhere([...]);
        break;
    case 'Unsaved':
        $query->andFilterWhere([...]);
        break;
    case 'Both':
        $query->andFilterWhere([...]);
        break;
```

Don't forget to add the `_selection` attribute to your Model class and to rules() as 'safe' in the Search Model class.

Comment: Let me test it out, I've never heard of this filterSelector to be honest

Answer (score 0):

You can try in two ways:

The first the simpler you assign to each button (saved, unsaved, both) the call of three separate cation of your controller
that invoke each a respective view connected to a single gridview each of these latter with the appropriate dataprovider

The second consists of controller you have the three dataprovider different as this example

```
    return $this->render('viewYourView', [
        '/modelContribuente' =>$modelContribuente,
        'dataProviderOne' => $providerOne,
        'dataProviderTwo' => $providerTwo,
        'dataProviderThree' => $providerThree,
    ]);(
```

In a single View you can create your three gridview everyone who uses the dataprovider appropriate and then visalizzare or hide gridviewn with JQuery functions controlled by buttons

Comment: First how leng is a records. Y manage 100.000 records in YII2 and teh performance are the main problem. Obviously 10.000.000of recorda are a problem in this case the first solution is the only one. Otherwise change project or boss

Comment: I love the 'Change the project or boss' part hahaah, because I'd love to change my boss.

He decided to use Yii2 for this project.. but whatever. :)